# How to sort a dictionary having keys as a string of numbers in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
a = {'100':12,'6':5,'88':3,'test':34, '67':7,'1':64 }
```

I want to sort this dictionary with respect to key so it looks like:

```
a = {'1':64,'6':5,'67':7,'88':3, '100':12,'test':34 }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like everyone else has pointed out, dictionaries have their own ordering and you can't just sort them like you would a list.

One thing I would like to add is that, if you just want to go through the elements of a dictionary in sorted order, that's just:

```
for k in sorted(a):
    print k, a[k] # or whatever.
```

If you'd rather have a list comprehension (per Alex):

```
sortedlist = [(k, a[k]) for k in sorted(a)]
```

I would like to point out that Alex's use of `key=int` won't work with your example because one of your keys is `'test'`.  If you really want he numbers sorted before the non-numerics, you'll have to pass in a `cmp` function:

```
def _compare_keys(x, y):
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        xint = False
    else:
        xint = True
    try:
        y = int(y)
    except ValueError:
        if xint:
            return -1
        return cmp(x.lower(), y.lower())
        # or cmp(x, y) if you want case sensitivity.
    else:
        if xint:
            return cmp(x, y)
        return 1

for k in sorted(a, cmp=_compare_keys):
    print k, a[k] # or whatever.
```

Or maybe you know enough about your keys to write a function to convert them into a string (or other object) that sorts right:

```
# Won't work for integers with more than this many digits, or negative integers.
MAX_DIGITS = 10
def _keyify(x):
    try:
        xi = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 'S{0}'.format(x)
    else:
        return 'I{0:0{1}}'.format(xi, MAX_DIGITS)

for k in sorted(a, key=_keyify):
    print k, a[k] # or whatever.
```

This would be much faster than using a `cmp` function.

Comment: I don't really like this as much as the other solutions. `_keyify` is unnecessarily rigid and I don't think quite as clean as some of the other solutions and your `_compare_keys` uses `cmp`, which is usually a bad sign. (It's also good form to keep `try` blocks for `try`/`except` as small as possible. I would put `return 'I{0:0{1}}'.format(xi, MAX_DIGITS)` in an `else` block.)

Comment: No, the solutions aren't optimized, they're just there as examples or starting points.  (It's hard to suggest a better solution without knowing what the actual key domain is.)  I like your solution except for the part where it breaks in Python 3.  I originally wrote `_compare_keys` with two two-line `try` blocks, but it was twice as long.  Using the `try` blocks to control execution flow eliminated the need for a `yint` boolean.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean that using the `cmp` parameter, as opposed to the function, is a "bad sign", and yes it is, but it's brought on by the incompletely defined key domain.  That's why I followed up with the `_keyify` solution.  Even better would be to create a new class for keys that can take a string input and sort itself properly, and use it as the dictionary's key instead, but I don't know if ben has that much control over the input dictionary.  And, yeah, I forgot about `else` blocks; too much C++ recently.  Fixed.

Comment: Thinking about it, normally I'd use `re` to take care of figuring out if something was an `int` or not, and not `try: x = int(x) ...`, but I felt that would be distracting from the main point of "use `key=` or `cmp=`", and at the risk of sounding like a broken sound card, I couldn't suggest a proper regular expression without knowing the key domain.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot sort a `dict` in Python as the `dict` type is inherently unordered. What you can do is sort the items before you used them using the `sorted()` built in function. You will also need a helper function to distinguish between your numerical and string keys:

```
def get_key(key):
    try:
        return int(key)
    except ValueError:
        return key
a = {'100':12,'6':5,'88':3,'test':34, '67':7,'1':64 }
print sorted(a.items(), key=lambda t: get_key(t[0]))
```

However in Python 3.1 (and 2.7) the `collections` module contains the [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)type that can be used to achieve the effect you want like below:

```
def get_key(key):
    try:
        return int(key)
    except ValueError:
        return key
a = {'100':12,'6':5,'88':3,'test':34, '67':7,'1':64 }
b = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda t: get_key(t[0])))
print(b)
```

Comment: This will not get the order OP wanted.

Comment: Hi Mawushe,

First let me thank you for your suggestion. But still the given code won't provide a desired solution.

Comment: You are both right gents I have update the answer to both sort by the  key and take into account the string nature of the keys.

Comment: OrderedDict is also available in Python 2.7…

Answer (score 5):

9 years ago I posted a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52306-to-sort-a-dictionary/) that *starts*

> Dictionaries can't be sorted -- a
>   mapping has no ordering!

and shows how to get sorted **lists** out of a dict's keys and values.

With today's Python, and your expressed-plus-implied specs, I'd suggest:

```
import sys

def asint(s):
    try: return int(s), ''
    except ValueError: return sys.maxint, s

sortedlist = [(k, a[k]) for k in sorted(a, key=asint)]
```

the `key=asint` is what tells `sorted` to treat those string keys as integers for sorting purposes, so that e.g. `'2'` sorts between `'1'` and `'12'`, rather than after them both -- that's what you appear to require, as well as having all non-all-digits keys sort after all 
all-digits ones.  If you need to also deal with all-digits key strings that express integers larger than sys.maxint, it's a bit trickier, but still doable:

```
class Infinity(object):
    def __cmp__(self, other): return 0 if self is other else 1
infinite = Infinity()
def asint(s):
    try: return int(s), ''
    except ValueError: return infinite, s
```

In general, you can get better answers faster if you specify your exact requirements more precisely from the start;-).

Comment: This will fail for the input OP specified because `int` will raise `ValueError` when it encounters `'test'`.

Comment: @ben, you're welcome, but SO's motto is "thanks are nice, but what really matters is the accept" -- once you've seen enough answers, accept the answer that helped you most, by clicking on the checkmark-shaped icon under the number at the answer's top left. This also gets you started on earning your own rep on SO, as well as rewarding with rep the answerer who has most helped you.

Comment: Note that `float('inf')` is already a number greater than all others.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries are unordered. You cannot sort one like you show because the resultant `a` is a dict, and dicts do not have order.

If you want, say, a list a list of the keys in sorted order, you can use code like

```
>>> def my_key(dict_key):
...     try:
...         return int(dict_key)
...     except ValueError:
...         return dict_key
...
>>> sorted(a, key=my_key)
['1', '6', '67', '88', '100', 'test']
```

This relies on the stupid Python behavior that instances of `str` are always greater than instances of `int`. (The behaviour is fixed in Python 3.) In an optimal design, the keys of your dict would be things you could compare sanely and you wouldn't mix in strings representing numbers with strings representing words.

If you want to keep the keys in always-sorted order, you can use the `bisect` module or implement a mapping that relies on a tree data structure. The `bisect` module does not accept a `key` argument like the sorting stuff because this would be potentially inefficient; you would use the decorate–use–undecorate pattern if you chose to use `bisect`, keeping a sorted list that depends on the result of the key function.

Comment: Note that maintaining a sorted list using bisect takes O(n**2) time.  The bisect will find the right place to insert in O(log n) time per item, but the insert still takes O(n) time per item due to the array-like nature of Python lists.

Comment: @Daniel Strutzbach, That depends on what you mean by "maintaining"; depending on usage you often can avoid the quadratic behavior of building a sorted list using insort. Using a list and `bisect` certainly does not give the ideal performance for insertion operations. If these operations are important, it is better to go with the "or implement a mapping that relies on a tree data structure". Since you've already done this for us, I upvoted your post which references your nice `sorteddict` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you install my [blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist) package, it includes a `sorteddict` type.  Then you could simply:

```
from blist import sorteddict

def my_key(dict_key):
       try:
              return int(dict_key)
       except ValueError:
              return dict_key

a = {'100':12,'6':5,'88':3,'test':34, '67':7,'1':64 }
print sorteddict(my_key, **a).keys()
```

Output:

```
['1', '6', '67', '88', '100', 'test']
```

Comment: 7-space indents aside `;)`, this is a good solution if you need a mapping that is always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is also the following:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(list(a.keys()), key = lambda x: (len(x),x))
sorted_dict = {k:a[k] for k in sorted_keys}
```

The most important part is `key = lambda x: (len(x),x)` which I took from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-numeric-strings-in-a-list/)