# sorting a dictionary of lists based on keys

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a dictionary having keys as string of numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548000/sorting-a-dictionary-having-keys-as-string-of-numbers-in-python)

I want to sort the dictionary of list based on value of keys. This is how it looks now

```
{'217': ['109'], 
 '214': ['111', '156', '159'], 
 '215': ['111'], 
 '219': ['111', '114', '212', '214’]}
```

But I want something like

```
{'214': ['111', '156', '159'], 
 '215': ['111'], 
 '217': ['109'],
 '219': ['111', '114', '212', '214’]}
```

Any suggestions?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries do not sort their keys in any particular order, because they are implemented as hash tables.  You can get the keys and values in sorted order, but not as a dict, using something like:

```
>>> mydict = {'217': ['109'], '214': ['111', '156', '159'], '215': ['111'], '219': ['111', '114', '212', '214']}
>>> [(k, mydict[k]) for k in sorted(mydict)]
[('214', ['111', '156', '159']), ('215', ['111']), ('217', ['109']), ('219', ['111', '114', '212', '214'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` (available on Python2.7 or 3.1+)

Using TokenMacGuy's comprehension:

```
collections.OrderedDict((k, mydict[k]) for k in sorted(mydict))
```

Comment: Do note that an `OrderedDict` doesn't keep keys sorted, but rather, returns them in the order they were inserted.  Since JBernardo is inserting them in sorted order, they will be returned as such, but if more keys are added later, the `OrderedDict` will have to be resorted.

Comment: that's why you need to sort it before...

Comment: I did notice, but maybe not everyone looking at your answer finds that obvious; I thought I would draw attention to that detail.