# Sorting Dictionary in python with the given Dict Format

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to convert my dict from

```
 results = {"r3":ab,"r1":ac,"r9":ab,"r12":ad,"r19":ae,"r11":ar,"r2":af,"r21":aa,
            "r31":a,"r99":ad,"r111":af,"r116":af,"r211":ar,"r221":aq,}
```

to

```
{"r1":ac,"r2":af,"r3":ab,"r9":ab,"r11":ar,"r12":ad,"r19":ae,"r21":aa,
     "r31":a,"r99":ad, "r111":af,"r116":af,"r211":ar,"r221":aq,}
```

I had tried with

```
json_data = json.dumps(results, sort_keys = True)
```

and with

```
(sorted(results.items(),reverse=False)) but not getting desired output
```

Help me to obtain properly sorted directly

Comment: dicts **cannot** be sorted. They are an unsorted container of data. You can switch to `OrderedDict`s by `Collections`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dictionary having keys as a string of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548000/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-having-keys-as-a-string-of-numbers-in-python)

Comment: `{"r1":ac,",,"r2":af` wat

Answer (score 0):

List of tuples would work better than `OrderedDict`:

```
results = {"r3":'ab',"r1":'ac',"r9":'ab',"r12":'ad',"r19":'ae',"r11":'ar',"r2":'af'}
results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].translate(None, 'r')))
#[('r1', 'ac'), ('r2', 'af'), ('r3', 'ab'), ('r9', 'ab'), ('r11', 'ar'), ('r12', 'ad'), ('r19', 'ae')]
```

Comment: Did you test this answer?

Comment: Is the `key` attribute really necessary here? Leave it out to sort keys then values, or set it to `lambda x: x[0]` for sorting of keys only. The translate thing throws a `TypeError` here.

Comment: I tested the answer, and if you exclude key the result would be `[('r1', 'ac'), ('r11', 'ar'), ('r12', 'ad')...` because `str` and `int` have different sorting rules.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
keysLessR = [int(item[1:]) for item in results.keys()]
keysLessR

[12, 11, 19, 31, 21, 211, 1, 2, 3, 9, 221, 99, 111, 116]
keysLessR.sort()

[1, 2, 3, 9, 11, 12, 19, 21, 31, 99, 111, 116, 211, 221]
orderedKeys = ['r'+str(item) for item in keysLessR]

orderedKeys
['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r9', 'r11', 'r12', 'r19', 'r21', 'r31', 'r99', 'r111', 'r116', 'r211', 'r221']

for item in orderedKeys:
  print item + ":" + results[item]    # for example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    print(OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key= lambda k: int(k[0][1:]))))
```

or more details:

```
    dict = {"r3":'ab',"r1":'ac',"r9":'ab',"r12":'ad',"r19":'ae',"r11":'ar',"r2":'af',"r21":'aa',"r31":'a',"r99":'ad',"r111":'af',"r116":'af',"r211":'ar',"r221":'aq'}
    sort_keys = sorted(dict, key=lambda k: (k[0], int(k[1:])))
    res_dic = OrderedDict()
    for k in sort_keys:
        if k is not res_dic:
            res_dic[k] = dict[k]
    print(res_dic)
```

OrderDictionary use to maintain state of key in which order we are creating.